# Loading and Unloading JavaScript with CSS Media Queries in mind

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, responsive-design

I'm using CSS Media Queries for making my website responsive:

```
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    // DESKTOP STYLING
}

@media (max-width:1200px) {
    // MOBILE STYLING
}
```

I use https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js to check for Media Query

```
if(min-width:1200px) {
    // DESKTOP JAVASCRIPT
} else {
    // MOBILE JAVASCRIPT
}
```

So initially everything works fine, when my screen is < 1200px it shows mobile version if its higher it shows desktop version (javascript works as well).

Problem now is when i start resizing the window for example:

```
1) LOADS DESKTOP JAVASCRIPT (EVERYTHING IS FINE)
2) RESIZE WINDOW < 1200px (SWITCH TO MOBILE TEMPLATE)
   LOADS MOBILE JAVASCRIPT (SITE BREAKS)
3) RESIZE WINDOW > 1200px (SWITCH TO DESKTOP TEMPLATE)
   LOADS DESKTOP JAVASCRIPT A SECOND TIME (SITE BREAKS EVEN MORE)
```

So i was wondering any ideas how to 'unload' javascript or maybe a elegant way to have two different javascript files loaded depending which media query is used ?

Comment: Maybe try using jQuery Mobile. http://jquerymobile.com/ ... Also technically you don't need to use JavaScript to make a website responsive. It can all be accomplished with CSS and fluid layouts. Could you please elaborate a bit more on how the JavaScript comes into play?

Comment: Well, i don't use JavaScript to make the Site responsive. I do that just by CSS (Media Queries, where i have designed two separate templates). But since the mobile and the desktop version are using the same DOM elements, the javascript still tries to run the slideshow for example. Which is one problem cause the most interactive elements are simplified in the mobile version.

So instead of a slideshow you just have static images.

Comment: Okay, I see. Sorry I misunderstood the entirety of your situation.

Answer (score 3):

First you could have one JavaScript (join the 2 together ) and have a controller which will verify if your window size is greater or not than 1200.

Or you could try to wrap the JavaScipt files into two objects, and create a third which will handle as a controller. Via Ajax you could load and unload the files ( nothing breaks because you have the controller still there ) and switch between them. This is a problem though because you will have to remove all the listeners when you make the switch and you will have to load another file which will take a small amount of time.

Hope this helps. Nice question by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the response, helly0d.

Well kinda hoped there was a more simply way to do it. But i guess that's the only way. Would be no problem if the javascript file would be very small, also i have to unbind all the handlers. Seems like awful much extra code for a simply switch :)

Comment: Why do you need two scripts for different sizes by the way? Can't you make the functions of the scripts as general as possible and set them parameters? Or do you load different HTML control through those 2 scripts ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a library like [Enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/), you could always code the triggers yourself, but if you have a "desktop slideshow" and a "mobile slideshow," you'll need to make sure you destroy the the inactive one on resize and Enquire has a nice API for that includes an unmatch trigger.

I'm dealing with the same slideshow plugin for my "desktop slideshow" and a "mobile slideshow," but would like different settings (e.g.- using a bottom aligned pager versus a next/prev navigation) which is easy to set on page load, but what if the device changes media queries breakpoints on orientation change, etc.